# How can i create a list or Array list for each "line" i print

Tags: java, list

I want to store each line it will get printed in different list or a data structure in general.

```
public class ReadFile 
{
    private Scanner x;


    public void openFile()
    {
        try {

            x=new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\kakos\\Downloads\\data.csv"));
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {

            System.out.println("could not find file");
        }

    }

    public void readFile()
    {
        List<String> list=new LinkedList<String>();

        while(x.hasNext())
        {
                System.out.print(x.nextLine()+"\n");

        }               
    }

    public void closeFile()
    {
        x.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Be more specific - what have you tried, what isn't working etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help on how to formulate a good question that will get you answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the code. I hope this is your query.

```
public void readFile()
    {
        List<String> list=new LinkedList<String>();

        while(x.hasNext())
        {
                list.add(x.nextLine());

        }               
    }
```